# How to increase frame rate in Android mode in Processing?

Tags: android, processing

i am using open source code from processing.js.com site,which has frame rate() method,

when i change frame rate,it shows changes in moving shapes in Java & Javascript mode but not in Android mode,
Why this happens?
How should i increase frame rate to fast my visualization ?

```
      // Set number of circles
  int count = 25;
  // Set maximum and minimum circle size
  int maxSize = 100;
  int minSize = 20;
  // Build float array to store circle properties
  float[][] e = new float[count][5];
  // Set size of dot in circle center
  float ds=2;
  // Selected mode switch
  int sel = 0;
  // Set drag switch to false
  boolean dragging=false;
  // If use drags mouse...
  void mouseDragged(){
    // Set drag switch to true
    dragging=true;
  }
  // If user releases mouse...
  void mouseReleased(){
    // ..user is no-longer dragging
    dragging=false;
  }

  // Set up canvas
  void setup(){
    // Frame rate
    frameRate(130);
    // Size of canvas (width,height)
    size(600,475);
    // Stroke/line/border thickness
    strokeWeight(1);
    // Initiate array with random values for circles
    for(int j=0;j< count;j++){
      e[j][0]=random(width); // X 
      e[j][1]=random(height); // Y
      e[j][2]=random(minSize,maxSize); // Radius        
      e[j][3]=random(-.5,.5); // X Speed
      e[j][4]=random(-.5,.5); // Y Speed    
    }
  }

  // Begin main draw loop (called 25 times per second)
  void draw(){
    // Fill background black
    background(0);
    // Begin looping through circle array
    for (int j=0;j< count;j++){
    // Disable shape stroke/border
    noStroke();
    // Cache diameter and radius of current circle
    float radi=e[j][2];
    float diam=radi/2;
    // If the cursor is within 2x the radius of current circle...
    if( dist(e[j][0],e[j][1],mouseX,mouseY) < radi ){
    // Change fill color to green.
    fill(64,187,128,100);
    // Remember user has circle "selected"  
    sel=1;
    // If user has mouse down and is moving...
    if (dragging){
      // Move circle to circle position
      e[j][0]=mouseX;
      e[j][1]=mouseY;
      }
    } else {
      // Keep fill color blue
      fill(64,128,187,100);
      // User has nothing "selected"
      sel=0;
    }
    // Draw circle
    ellipse(e[j][0],e[j][1],radi,radi);
    // Move circle
    e[j][0]+=e[j][3];
    e[j][1]+=e[j][4];


    /* Wrap edges of canvas so circles leave the top
    and re-enter the bottom, etc... */ 
    if( e[j][0] < -diam      ){ e[j][0] = width+diam;  } 
    if( e[j][0] > width+diam ){ e[j][0] = -diam;       }
    if( e[j][1] < 0-diam     ){ e[j][1] = height+diam; }
    if( e[j][1] > height+diam){ e[j][1] = -diam;       }

    // If current circle is selected...
    if (sel==1) {
      // Set fill color of center dot to white..
      fill(255,255,255,255);
      // ..and set stroke color of line to green.
      stroke(128,255,0,100);      
    } else {            
      // otherwise set center dot color to black.. 
      fill(0,0,0,255);
      // and set line color to turquoise.
      stroke(64,128,128,255);      
    }

    // Loop through all circles
    for(int k=0;k< count;k++){
      // If the circles are close...
      if( dist(e[j][0],e[j][1],e[k][0],e[k][1]) < radi){
        // Stroke a line from current circle to adjacent circle
        line(e[j][0],e[j][1],e[k][0],e[k][1]);
      }
    }
    // Turn off stroke/border
    noStroke();      
    // Draw dot in center of circle
    rect(e[j][0]-ds,e[j][1]-ds,ds*2,ds*2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Will you please paste some here ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani I add source code.

Comment: Are you wanting to change the frame rate or are you wanting to increase the speed of the animation? I'm not sure what's going on with your frame rate issue, but I can tell you a better way to increase the speed of the animation.

Comment: @spex tell me how to increase speed of animation

Comment: @spex tell me how to increase speed of animation,I think you forgot

Comment: @SagarNikam You're right, I didn't notice your message until now, I'll post an answer today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the speed of the circles in your sketch, it is easier to simply change the speed value.

In your setup() function, you set the following:

```
 e[j][3] = random(-.5, .5); // X Speed
 e[j][4] = random(-.5, .5); // Y Speed
```

These values are used later to move the circles in the draw() function:

```
// Move circle
e[j][0] += e[j][3];
e[j][1] += e[j][4];
```

You could simply change the `e[j][3]` and `e[j][4]` values being set in your setup() function, or you could replace them with a variable which is assigned in the global scope at the beginning of your code. The following is the quick modification I would make. Take note of the variable `float speed = 0.5;` set near the beginning of the code. If you make that value larger, the movement of the circles will be faster.

```
// Set number of circles
int count = 25;
// Set maximum and minimum circle size
int maxSize = 100;
int minSize = 20;
// Set speed
float speed = 0.5;
// Build float array to store circle properties
float[][] e = new float[count][5];
// Set size of dot in circle center
float ds = 2;
// Selected mode switch
int sel = 0;
// Set drag switch to false
boolean dragging = false;

// If use drags mouse...
void mouseDragged() {
  // Set drag switch to true
  dragging = true;
}

// If user releases mouse...
void mouseReleased() {
  // ..user is no-longer dragging
  dragging = false;
}

// Set up canvas
void setup() {
  // Size of canvas (width,height)
  size(600, 475);
  // Stroke/line/border thickness
  strokeWeight(1);
  // Initiate array with random values for circles
  for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    e[j][0] = random(width); // X 
    e[j][1] = random(height); // Y
    e[j][2] = random(minSize, maxSize); // Radius
    e[j][3] = random(-speed, speed); // X Speed
    e[j][4] = random(-speed, speed); // Y Speed
  }
}

// Begin main draw loop (called 25 times per second)
void draw() {
  // Fill background black
  background(0);
  // Begin looping through circle array
  for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    // Disable shape stroke/border
    noStroke();
    // Cache diameter and radius of current circle
    float radi = e[j][2];
    float diam = radi / 2;
    // If the cursor is within 2x the radius of current circle...
    if (dist(e[j][0], e[j][1], mouseX, mouseY) < radi) {
      // Change fill color to green.
      fill(64, 187, 128, 100);
      // Remember user has circle "selected"
      sel = 1;
      // If user has mouse down and is moving...
      if (dragging) {
        // Move circle to circle position
        e[j][0] = mouseX;
        e[j][1] = mouseY;
      }
    } else {
      // Keep fill color blue
      fill(64, 128, 187, 100);
      // User has nothing "selected"
      sel = 0;
    }
    // Draw circle
    ellipse(e[j][0], e[j][1], radi, radi);
    // Move circle
    e[j][0] += e[j][3];
    e[j][1] += e[j][4];


    /* Wrap edges of canvas so circles leave the top
    and re-enter the bottom, etc... */
    if (e[j][0] < -diam) {
      e[j][0] = width + diam;
    }
    if (e[j][0] > width + diam) {
      e[j][0] = -diam;
    }
    if (e[j][1] < 0 - diam) {
      e[j][1] = height + diam;
    }
    if (e[j][1] > height + diam) {
      e[j][1] = -diam;
    }

    // If current circle is selected...
    if (sel == 1) {
      // Set fill color of center dot to white..
      fill(255, 255, 255, 255);
      // ..and set stroke color of line to green.
      stroke(128, 255, 0, 100);
    } else {
      // otherwise set center dot color to black.. 
      fill(0, 0, 0, 255);
      // and set line color to turquoise.
      stroke(64, 128, 128, 255);
    }

    // Loop through all circles
    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
      // If the circles are close...
      if (dist(e[j][0], e[j][1], e[k][0], e[k][1]) < radi) {
        // Stroke a line from current circle to adjacent circle
        line(e[j][0], e[j][1], e[k][0], e[k][1]);
      }
    }
    // Turn off stroke/border
    noStroke();
    // Draw dot in center of circle
    rect(e[j][0] - ds, e[j][1] - ds, ds * 2, ds * 2);
  }
}
```